# Use sum of binary values as constraint coefficient in integer programming constraint

Tags: r, mixed-integer-programming, lpsolve

I am trying to formulate a shelf-optimization integer programming algorithm  in lpsolveAPI and wish to add a constraint whereby the same number of each product is on each selected shelf (S):

f[image: constraint]

My difficulty is accessing and using the sums as constraints (specifically X<sub>ij</sub>)

I can reformulate to make it linear without too much problems (please excuse the pseudocode):

```
sum(X_ij)*F_ij - sum(F_ij) = 0
```

This operation could affect the choice of X itself, thus I need it to be dynamic (otherwise I could just change the values post-solve) How can I access these values, or code the F values to be equal?

The linear program creates a binary solution through a series of constraints to place products on shelves (it may place on one shelf or two shelves at the moment), there are four shelves. Then there is a second set which allows a number of products on those shelves which are non-zero, constrained by the width of the products against the length of the shelves with a given maximum of products on all shelves (8 for most of them, though this is somewhat arbitrary), maximising the product profit. All this works as expected. However, I wish to add a constraint such that the number of products on two or more shelves are the same i.e. four on one and four on the other. Given that the number of shelves used can be 1 or 2, I cannot simply divide the values. Further, as which shelves are occupied are decided by constraints, I cannot simply use P1S1 = P1S2 (unless I could select the occupied shelves, which I am failing to do)

Here is a minimal example of what I am trying to do (please excuse the inelegant code as I am doing this for the first time) the dataset is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P886LY1oVeKCCjg_Txr6CrM_y6x87-_K/view?usp=sharing):

```
library(lpSolveAPI)

shelves <- data.frame(Sl_i = c(151, 200, 180, 218),
                      Sh_i = c(30, 30, 30, 36))

datatable <- read.csv("~/Desktop/sales/datatable.txt", sep="")

S = 4  # number of shelves
P = 40 # number of products

Shelf_choice <-
  make.lp(0, nrow(mydata) * 2) # create the lp object with decision variables == longitude of data.frame

#### SET OBJECTIVE FUNCTION ####


#### Set controls for the model ####

lp.control(Shelf_choice,
           sense = "max",
           timeout = 10,
           presolve = "none") ## timeout prevents getting stuck
set.objfn(Shelf_choice, c(rep(rep(0, nrow(
  mydata
)), 1), mydata$Pu_j)) # maximize profit (Pu_j)

set.type(Shelf_choice, 1:nrow(mydata), "binary") # present on shelf or not
set.type(Shelf_choice, 1:nrow(mydata) + nrow(mydata), "integer") # number of product j on shelf


### Assure that each product appears on minimum number of shelves (1 in this case)
Add_productShelf_constraint <- function (prod_index) {
  cargo_cols <-
    (0:(S - 1)) * P + prod_index  # # index of products by column (eg. 1,41,81,121)
  add.constraint(
    Shelf_choice,
    rep(1, S),
    # repeat value the same number of times as shelves
    indices = cargo_cols,
    type = ">=",
    rhs = mydata$smin_j[prod_index]
  ) # value of minimum number of shelves
}

lapply(1:P, Add_productShelf_constraint) # list apply this for every product

### Assure that product appears no more than the number of shelves permitted (2 in this case)
Add_productShelfMAX_constraint <- function (prod_index) {
  cargo_cols <-
    (0:(S - 1)) * P + prod_index   # index of products by column (eg. 1,41,81,121)
  add.constraint(
    Shelf_choice,
    rep(1, S),
    # repeat value the same number of times as shelves
    indices = cargo_cols,
    type = "<=",
    rhs = mydata$smax_j[prod_index]
  ) # value of minimum number of shelves
}

lapply(1:P, Add_productShelfMAX_constraint) # list apply this for every product



### Third Constraint: Products too tall for a shelf are excluded

Add_height_constraint <-
  function (prod_index) {
    # this needs to be improved
    add.constraint(Shelf_choice,
                   1,
                   indices = prod_index,
                   type = "=",
                   rhs = 0)
  }
lapply(which(mydata$height == 0), Add_height_constraint) # Here we select the colums which have 0 (don't fit), and set the value to 0


## Products are on consecutive shelves - this currently only works for two shelves
Add_nextshelf_constraint <- function (prod_index) {
  mat1 <- combn(1:S, 2)[, which(combn(1:S, 2)[2, ] - combn(1:S, 2)[1, ] != 1)]
  cargo_cols <- (0:(S - 1)) * P + prod_index
  result <- matrix(cargo_cols[mat1], nrow = 2)
  
  for (i in 1:ncol(result)) {
    add.constraint(
      Shelf_choice,
      c(1, 1),
      indices = result[, i],
      type = "<=",
      rhs = 1
    )
  }
}
lapply(1:P, Add_nextshelf_constraint)




### Product facings only appear on selected shelves (where Xij = 1)

Add_FF_constraint1 <- function (prod_index) {
  Y01col <- prod_index
  print(Y01col)
  FF_col <- prod_index + nrow(mydata)
  add.constraint(
    Shelf_choice,
    c(1, -100),
    indices = c(FF_col, Y01col),
    type = "<=",
    rhs = 0
  )
}
lapply(1:nrow(mydata), Add_FF_constraint1) #

Add_FF_constraint2 <- function (prod_index) {
  Y01col <- prod_index
  FF_col <- prod_index + nrow(mydata)
  add.constraint(
    Shelf_choice,
    c(1, -1),
    indices = c(FF_col, Y01col),
    type = ">=",
    rhs = 0
  )
}
lapply(1:nrow(mydata), Add_FF_constraint2) #



#### Sum of product widths on shelves does not exceed shelf length
Add_FijShelflength_constraint <- function (shelf_index) {
  shelf_cols_mydata <- ((1:(P)) + (shelf_index - 1) * P)
  FF_shelf_cols <- ((1:(P)) + (shelf_index - 1) * P)  + nrow(mydata)
  
  add.constraint(
    Shelf_choice,
    c(mydata$Pw_j[shelf_cols_mydata]),
    # width of each product
    indices = c(FF_shelf_cols),
    # indices of products per shelf in Fij Matrix
    rhs = shelves$Sl_i[shelf_index]
  ) # length of each shelf
  
}
lapply(1:S, Add_FijShelflength_constraint) # list apply this by shelf index

## add minimum number of total facings
Add_min_facings_constraint <- function (prod_index) {
  FjSi_cols <-
    (0:(S - 1)) * P + prod_index + nrow(mydata) # index of the products by column in out table
  add.constraint(
    Shelf_choice,
    rep(1, S),
    # repeat value the same number of times as shelves
    indices = FjSi_cols,
    # index of products by column (eg. 1,41,81,121)
    type = ">=",
    rhs = mydata$Fmin_j[prod_index]
  ) # value of minimum number of products
}
lapply(1:P, Add_min_facings_constraint) # list apply this for every product

## add maximum number of facings
Add_max_facings_constraint <- function (prod_index) {
  FjSi_cols <-
    (0:(S - 1)) * P + prod_index + nrow(mydata)
  add.constraint(
    Shelf_choice,
    rep(1, S),
    # repeat value the same number of times as shelves
    indices = FjSi_cols,
    # index of products by column (eg. 1,41,81,121)
    type = "<=",
    rhs = mydata$Fmax_j[prod_index]
  ) # value of maximum number of products
}
lapply(1:P, Add_max_facings_constraint) # list apply this for every product

solve(Shelf_choice)

get.objective(Shelf_choice) # gives the total value of the facings

### Tabulates the results ####
test <- matrix(get.variables(Shelf_choice),
               ncol = S * 2,
               byrow = F)
rownames(test) <- paste0("Product", 1:40)
colnames(test) <- c(rep(paste0("Shelf", 1:4), 2))

test[, 5:8] # shows the product placements (uneven products between shelves)
#
```

Results:

| Product | Shelf 1 | Shelf 2 | Shelf 3 | Shelf 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| - | - | - | - | - |
| P11 | 1 | 7 | 0 | 0 |
| P16 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 0 |

I need, for example, that product 11 has the same number of products on each shelf (4 on each)

I have tried to create a constraint such as :

```
Sum_Xshelf_constraint <- function (prod_index) {
  binary_sum <-
    sum(get.variables(Shelf_choice)[(0:(S - 1)) * P + prod_index])
  total_Fij <-
    sum(get.variables(Shelf_choice)[(0:(S - 1)) * P + prod_index + nrow(df)])
  
  total_cols <-
    (0:(S - 1)) * P + prod_index + nrow(df) # index of the products in Fij
  
  for (i in 1:length(total_cols)) {
    add.constraint(
      Shelf_choice,
      c(binary_sum),
      indices = c(total_cols[i]),
      type = "<=",
      rhs = total_Fij
    )                  # value of minimum number which is Fmin_j
  }
}
### At least one product on a shelf
lapply(1:P, Sum_Xshelf_constraint)
```

This unsurprisingly will not work before solving, and once solved it has no effect.

Any ideas how to achieve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I suspect this may help (but I am not sure: the code is difficult to read): The product of a continuous or integer variable with a binary variable can be linearized using standard techniques.

Comment: Here is an example that looks similar: https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2017/05/linearizing-average.html

Comment: Thanks for the response @ErwinKalvelagen, and I apologise for my poor coding which does make it difficult to read. However, the "binary_sum" variable is indeed a sum and can take the values of either 0,1 or 2. This makes it a quadratic constraint. I am redoing it all (trying) to use a MIQLP for a Linear decision variable with Quadratic constraint. It would seem that `Gurobi` seems to be a possible, although not open source, solution. Any open source suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not really needed. The individual terms can be linearized.

Answer (score 0):

It your decision variables are PiSj (#ith Product on jth Shelf) then a series of chained equations could work:

```
P1S1 = P1S2
P1S2 = P1S3
P1S3 = P1S4
```

That kind of simplicity can sometimes markedly improve performance.

Comment: I wish it were that simple. The problem is that product 1 could be on shelf 1 and shelf 2, but perhaps not on shelf 3 or 4 for example, or perhaps even only on one shelf. Thus what is required is to "know" how many shelves it is on and multiply the value for one shelf by that number and divide by the total number on all shelves to assure that the number on occupied shelves is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have to answer my own problem here:

**It is not possible.**

Reading carefully it seems that this particular constraint is **quadratic**... (http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/)

*"Suppose that xj must take an integer value i:*

*yj / y0 = i*

*or*

*yj = i * y0*

*Unfortunately, this constraint can't be handled by lpsolve since it is quadratic."*

I will edit this answer with the quadratic solution when it is complete. Thought I had better post this now so that others don't put too much effort into trying to solve it.

Thanks!